# When i click on header, no preferences show up

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

I am working of settings activity for my application. I seted up two headers for preferences and then i made fragment for each header. Problem is when i click on header, nothing shows up. Thank you for your help.

Here is my preference activity

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.prefheads, target);

    }
}
```

Here is first fragment

```
public class Prefs1 extends PreferenceFragment {

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragment_prefs1);
        }

    }


}
```

Here is second fragment:

```
public class Prefs2 extends PreferenceFragment {


    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragment_prefs2);
        }

    }

}
```

XML files:
Headers

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <header
        android:fragment="com.example.lubys.prefs.prefs1"
        android:title="First category"
        android:summary="This doesnt need summary" />
    <header
        android:fragment="com.example.lubys.prefs.prefs2"
        android:title="Second cat"
        android:summary="This is awful summary">
        </header>
</preference-headers>
```

Fragment1:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.lubys.prefs.prefs1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="the title"
        android:key="key2">
    <EditTextPreference android:title="Your Name"
        android:key="username"
        android:summary="Please provide your username"></EditTextPreference>
    <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Application Updates"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:summary="This option if selected will allow the application to check for latest versions."
        android:key="applicationUpdates" />

        <ListPreference
            android:title="Download Details"
            android:summary="Select the kind of data that you would like to download"
            android:key="downloadType"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:entries="@array/c"
            android:entryValues="@array/c" />

</PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Fragment2:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.lubys.prefs.prefs1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="sms"
        android:key="pref_key_storage_settings">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="saas"
            android:summary="asde"
            android:title="Something"
            android:defaultValue="false"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if u didn't get:

> **java.lang.RuntimeException:**
>
> ***Subclasses of PreferenceActivity must override isValidFragment(String)*** to verify that the Fragment class is valid!
>   *XXX* has not checked if fragment *YYY* is valid.

[isValidFragment Android API 19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973034/isvalidfragment-android-api-19)

[when android's isValidFragment() from PreferenceActivity gets called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954072/when-androids-isvalidfragment-from-preferenceactivity-gets-called)

http://securityintelligence.com/new-vulnerability-android-framework-fragment-injection#.VRGSv1V_NBc