# Android Studio Settings Activity doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

As far as I can understand from the documentation the settings activity which comes as a template with Android Studio should work. However, it doesn't seem to launch anything on my phone.

I understand that it's meant to work for both tablets and phones.
I'm running Android 5.0 and I have successfully used it as a test device before.
I have yet to test it on a tablet.

Well, I'm using the default template that's supplied with android studio for the settings activity. I didn't post it since it extends across several pages (5 xml files and 1 class file).

http://www.pastebin.com/kehbMSqg -SettingsActivity.class. (That's the class which I set to launch.)

http://pastebin.com/GHjZRn68 -pref_data_sync.xml

http://pastebin.com/0FaaH8zR -pref_general.xml

http://pastebin.com/yixMwAaJ -pref_headers.xml

http://pastebin.com/46W1dREG -pref_notification.xml

Any help would be useful
Thanks!

Comment: Code?  How about a Logcat?

Comment: Whenever you make a question on SO then write related code any the logcat too if you get any error

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to a fix for a [fragment injection vulnerability](https://securityintelligence.com/new-vulnerability-android-framework-fragment-injection/) that was patched in KITKAT. If you are running the app for a targetSdkVersion since KITKAT, an exception will be thrown when the SettingsActivity tries to launch a PreferenceFragment.

You need to override the `PreferenceActivity.isValidFragment()` method. For the Settings Activity template in Android Studio 1.3.2 you can use:

```java
@Override
protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
    return fragmentName.equals(GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName())
            || fragmentName.equals(NotificationPreferenceFragment.class.getName())
            || fragmentName.equals(DataSyncPreferenceFragment.class.getName());
}
```

Related stackoverflow post:
[isValidFragment Android API 19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973034/isvalidfragment-android-api-19)